# Angular route when() without mapping to controller or template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

It's possible to use when() without mapping to any controller or template?

This is how I have configured my routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/presentations/:id', {});
});
```

I need to use routeParams in my controller:

```
app.controller('PresentationController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

This doesn't work. I don't need ngView but I added it in case is needed. My controller is already loaded with the ng-controller directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to continuously watch the `$routeParams.id` for changes in this case: http://plnkr.co/edit/x2cPxVWPqVePDule1aOk?p=preview

```js
$scope.$watch(function () { return $routeParams.id; }, function (newVal) {
  if (typeof newVal === 'undefined') return;
  $scope.id = newVal;
})
```

Also, having an `ng-view` in the template is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). With that $watch I can track url changes, works perfectly. But I have another problem, when the page loads for the first time, $routeParams is undefined when my controller is being loaded, i can reference it in the html and it works but not in the controller. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @PedroGarcía Why do you need to reference it? Can you create an updated example from my demo where it doesn't work?

Comment: I couldn't find how to change the default url in plunker. However i added some comments in the js file explaining where is the problem . http://plnkr.co/edit/raDtomFubQ56w6oiBvZT?p=preview

Comment: @PedroGarcía You _should_ do all work (e.g. loading the content) inside the `$watch`. Only the `$watcher` will be executed over and over again as the `$routeParams.id` changes, the rest of the controller will not be. Also, the first time around, the `$routeParams.id` may not be set because the order of execution of the controller and the router is not determined. Alternatively, you could use one route in the `$routeProvider` with your whole app's template rendered in `ng-view`. This will load the controller (and the template) over and over as the route changes, including the first time.

Comment: That clarifies it a lot! I am going for the last option and follow the angular way. Thanks :D