# Angular simple routing without templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am looking for simple solution with Angular how to handle routes.

I have page generated by server with simple google map and little logic which is in 3 separated controllers.

Now i want to hook routing inside of this. Just simple routing. When I move with map and get new coordinas i want to push them into current url as param "?position=10.11,50.23". I want to use history push state with hashbang backup.

In other part of application i want to listen on change of this parameter (some $watch maybe?). And i want to use same code for detecting change to be used when page is loaded first.

I used CanJS in previous project, where this was absolutely simple, but in Angular i cant event make baby step to correct result :)

PS: this is just cut of minimal usecase.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not really need angular routing to do that. Routing in angular is usually used to replace `ng-view` with different templates [though it can be used for other things as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181440/angular-route-when-without-mapping-to-controller-or-template).

Your requirements can be met by using the `$location` service and setting up a `$watch`:

```js
$scope.$watch(function () { return $location.search().position; }, function (newVal) {
  $scope.params = newVal || 'No params';
});

$scope.setParams = function (val) {
  $location.search('position', val);
};
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oAtAisjFhaRnAlPAqbIg)

Launch the live-preview in a separate window to see the parameters change in the window address bar.

**Update:** The Demo doesn't work on plnkr.co anymore. Possibly because they have changed how they use the embedded mode.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I totally missed $location. Everytime I ended on $route :)

Comment: Thanks. Also, to make this work, I needed to enable html5mode.

Comment: @suzanshakya Can you post an updated example where it does work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know CanJS, but in angular it is pretty easy as well.

First use: `$location.search({parameter1:'someValue', parameter2: 'someOtherValue'})` to set you url -- the history will be updated automatically.

Then the most elegant way to detect any changes in url is to use (one of) two built-in events:
`$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess`, like that:

```
    $scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        // your staff goes here
    });
    $scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
        // or here (or both if needed)
    });
```

To get the search parameters just use `$location.search()` in one of the above methods.

Comment: Would this also work if the user lands directly on a URL? I am not sure whether `$locationChangeStart/Success` events are fired then.

Comment: @musically_ut do you mean: user changes url in the browser, manually? (if so do not think anything can help to prevent reloading the app)

Comment: I was referring to the case when the URL already has `#?position=XYZ` when the app is loaded. This can happen if the user reloads the current page or if he forwards a link to someone else. I don't think the `$locationChange{Start/Sucess}` events are fired in that case (I may be wrong), and the application would need to load its state from `$location.search()` anyway. But +1 for pointing out the events; they had slipped my mind.

Comment: @musically_ut actually dunno :-) but my rough guess is that we need to check search parameters of url by our own.

Comment: _Or_ you can just set up a `$watch` on it and not worry about how the user got there. :)

Comment: @musically_ut yeah surely :-) (one little downside with `$watch` is that it is bit less efficient, as it is checked at each `$digest` cycle)